# why opening a port is so difficult in ubuntu?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I have searched around and I have run these commands

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

And I rebooted the box. I had no luck.

What am I missing? IS there a universal way to do this thing in ubuntu? I remember in fedora I just need to edit  a text file and make it happen.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have run

```
ufw allow 5432
```

and I ran

```
 ufw status
```

I got this result

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I still cannot access 5432!

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read up on [UFW - Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Comment: Is anything missing of my commands for this little task?